# Let $V$ be finite-dimensional unitary space. Prove: $(\forall U \in L(V) )( \forall x,y \in V, ||x|| \leq 1) ||y|| - | < Ux | y > | \geq 0 .$

Tags: vector-spaces

> Let $V$ be finite-dimensional unitary space. Prove:
>   $$ (\forall U \in L(V) )( \forall x,y \in V, ||x|| \leq 1) ||y|| - | < Ux | y > | \geq 0 .$$

I don't even know how to start ( tried to prove it directly but I got nowhere). Any hint helps!

Comment: A hypothesis is missing: if $U=2Id$, $x=y$, we have a problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated, the inequality is wrong.

Take $U(x) = 2x$ and $x=y$ with $\Vert x \Vert = 1$. You get

$$\Vert y \Vert - \vert \langle Ux,  y \rangle \vert = - 1 <0$$

Comment: This was task on exam so I haven't even checked if it is true. Thanks!

Comment: @user560461 Did the exam actually say $U\in L(V)$, or was it some other condition that you translated? (For example if we know that $U$ is _unitary_, as suggested by the notation, then things are different...)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich no, but can you show me what would proof be like if $U$ was unitary?

Comment: @user560461 If $U$ is unitary then $|\langle Ux,y\rangle|\le||Ux||\,||y||=||x||\,||y||=||y||$.